# creating a list of tuples based on successive items of initial list

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

```
test = ['a', 'b', 'c','d']
```

I would like to obtain a list as follows:

```
[('a','b'),('b','c'),('c','d')]
```

I have tried applying iterator() to the list and using next() but this doesn't achieve the desired result

Comment: `[(test[i], test[i+1]) for i in range(len(test)-1)]`

Comment: `list(zip(test[:-1], test[1:]))`